# Jpcap: IP packet header length

Tags: java, networking, jpcap

In JPCap i obtain the header length of the IP packet by the following code

```
   IPPacket IP_pac = (IPPacket) packet;
   System.out.println(IP_pac.len); // header length
```

i obtain the data length of the IP packet by

```
    System.out.println(IP_pac.data.length);
```

Now the problem is that the IP packet(IPV4) length should b 20 bytes when the data length of the IP packet is 0.but the results display the header length of the IP packet as 60 and 54. 
Secondly, do i consider these lengths of IP_pac.data.length as bytes by default?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/javadoc/jpcap/packet/IPPacket.html), the length is a short:

```
public short length
```

`packet.data` gives you a `byte[]`, so calling `.length` on this returns a `int` (like on all other arrays).

Comment: So i have to convert it into bytes from int? (inorder to say that 20,30 etc bytes of the payload).

Comment: if you want the payload length, `packet.data.length` is fine. You also get this info in _Total Length_ of the IP packet header (as well as the _Internet Header Length_). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4 for more info.